# How to add all tab completitions to my current command?

Tags: zsh

So I've typed a command (pacman -S perl-) and I hit tab and see that there are a whole bunch of completions (about 40), and I realize that I want to run every single completion (so I don't accidentally install from CPAN what is already a builtin).

How do I run all completions of a command?

BONUS: How do I run more than one and less than all of the commands (without typing them in individually)?

Example situation (the actual situation):

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ❯❯❯ pacman -S perl-<Tab>                     ⏎
-- packages --
perl                       perl-IPC-Run3
perl-ack                   perl-libwww
perl-Archive-Zip           perl-Locale-Gettext
perl-Authen-SASL           perl-LWP-MediaTypes
perl-Benchmark-Timer       perl-LWP-Protocol-https
perl-Capture-Tiny          perl-MailTools
perl-common-sense          perl-MIME-tools
perl-Compress-Bzip2        perl-Mozilla-CA
perl-Convert-BinHex        perl-Net-DNS
perl-Crypt-SSLeay          perl-Net-HTTP
perl-DBI                   perl-Net-IP
perl-Digest-HMAC           perl-Net-SMTP-SSL
perl-Encode-Locale         perl-Net-SSLeay
perl-Error                 perl-Path-Class
perl-Exporter-Lite         perl-Probe-Perl
perl-ExtUtils-Depends      perl-Regexp-Common
perl-ExtUtils-PkgConfig    perl-Socket6
perl-File-Copy-Recursive   perl-Sys-CPU
perl-File-Listing          perl-TermReadKey
perl-File-Next             perl-Test-Pod
perl-File-Which            perl-Test-Script
perl-Getopt-Tabular        perl-TimeDate
perl-HTML-Parser           perl-Try-Tiny
perl-HTML-Tagset           perl-URI
perl-HTTP-Cookies          perl-WWW-RobotRules
perl-HTTP-Daemon           perl-XML-LibXML
perl-HTTP-Date             perl-XML-NamespaceSupport
perl-HTTP-Message          perl-XML-Parser
perl-HTTP-Negotiate        perl-XML-SAX
perl-IO-HTML               perl-XML-SAX-Base
perl-IO-Socket-INET6       perl-XML-Simple
perl-IO-Socket-SSL         perl-YAML
perl-IO-stringy            perl-YAML-Syck
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own solution to deal with,

- To apply matching for completion results.
- To insert all the completion matches into the command line.
- To activate menu selection and select the completion more than one.

---

**To apply matching for completion results**, it could be done with the [`_match`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fmatch).
Here is an example `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
# below is same as the zsh default effect
# zstyle ':completion:*::::' completer _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*::::' completer _complete _match _ignored

# I don't like expand-or-complete to <Tab>, so I moved it to <C-x><Tab>
bindkey '^I' complete-word
bindkey '^X^I' expand-or-complete
```

Now, it could be ok to use `*`s to get the effects like this:

```
% ls m*e* ;# I have some local files that matches the glob.
main.epro    mem.c     mem.pro       modentry.c   module.o     modules.stamp
makepro.awk  mem.epro  mem.syms      module.c     module.pro
math.epro    mem.o     mkmakemod.sh  module.epro  module.syms

% git m*e*<Tab>
;# This prompts completions rather than expands the local files
;# like this:
% git merge
merge  -- join two or more development histories together
merge-base  -- find as good a common ancestor as possible for a merge
merge-file   -- run a three-way file merge
merge-index  -- run merge for files needing merging
merge-one-file  -- standard helper-program to use with git merge-index
merge-tree  -- show three-way merge without touching index
mergetool  -- run merge conflict resolution tools to resolve merge conflicts
mktree       -- build tree-object from git ls-tree formatted text
m*e*
```

**To insert all the compliteon matches into the command line**, it cloud be done with the [`all-matches`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fall_005fmatches). If you have the below snippets in your `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
zle -C all-matches complete-word _my_generic
zstyle ':completion:all-matches::::' completer _all_matches
zstyle ':completion:all-matches:*' old-matches only
_my_generic () {
  local ZSH_TRACE_GENERIC_WIDGET=  # works with "setopt nounset"
  _generic "$@"
}
bindkey '^X^a' all-matches
```

typing <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Control-x</kbd>,<kbd>Control-a</kbd> inserts the completion matches to the command line.
For example:

```
% vim string.<Tab>
string.c     string.epro  string.syms
;# then hit <C-x><C-a>
% vim string.c string.epro string.syms
```

**To activate menu selection and select the completion more than one**, it could be done by customizing `menuselect` keymap.
([From `zhmodules(1)` 22.7.3 Menu selection](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection))

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=0
zmodload zsh/complist
bindkey -M menuselect "^[a" accept-and-hold
bindkey -M menuselect '^[^[' vi-insert
```

This activete menu selection for the completion results. During the menu selection is active, typing <kbd>M-a</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc-a</kbd>) inserts the selected entry and advances the "menu cursor" to next entry.
For example session:

```
% ls sig*
sigcount.h    signals.h    signals.syms   signames.o     signames1.awk
signals.c     signals.o    signames.c     signames.pro   signames2.awk
signals.epro  signals.pro  signames.epro  signames.syms

% vim sig<Tab> ;# this lists the matches
sigcount.h     signals.epro   signals.syms   signames.epro  signames1.awk
signals.c      signals.h      signames.c     signames.syms  signames2.awk

;# hitting <Tab> second time, the "menu cursor" appears and
;# the first entry will be activated
;# Note: "[[]]" denotes the "menu cursor" here
% vim sigcount.h
[[sigcount.h]] signals.epro   signals.syms   signames.epro  signames1.awk
signals.c      signals.h      signames.c     signames.syms  signames2.awk

;# then  hit <M-a>(Esc a)
;# "sigcount.h" is now in the command line and
;# the "menu cursor" points "signals.c" now.
% vim sigcout.h signals.c
sigcount.h     signals.epro   signals.syms   signames.epro  signames1.awk
[[signals.c]]  signals.h      signames.c     signames.syms  signames2.awk

;# then <Tab><Tab>
% vim sigcount.h signals.h
sigcount.h     signals.epro   signals.syms   signames.epro  signames1.awk
signals.c    [[signals.h]]    signames.c     signames.syms  signames2.awk
```

So, you could select multiple entries in the completion results to hit <kbd>M-a</kbd>(or <kbd>Esc-a</kbd>) as you like.

*Below paragraph is not bad to know.*
In this expample configration, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> (we did `bindkey -M menuselect '^[^[' vi-insert` in the above snippets) while the menu selection is active, it allows us to interactively limit the completion result based on input patterns.

```
;# activate "menu selection" and hit <Esc><Esc>,
;# the "interacitve:" mode will be shown at this point.
% vim sig*
interactive: sig[]
[[sigcount.h]] signals.epro   signals.syms   signames.epro  signames1.awk
signals.c      signals.h      signames.c     signames.syms  signames2.awk

;# hitting "*awk" while interactive is activetad,
;# it colud limit the completion to "sig*awk"
% vim sig*awk
interactive: sig[]
[[signames1.awk]]signames2.awk
sig*awk
```

*I'm not sure I describe correctly, so here is the portion of the zsh doc for the menu selection's "interactive mode".*

> vi-insert
>
> this toggles between normal and interactive mode; in interactive mode the keys bound to self-insert and self-insert-unmeta insert into the command line as in normal editing mode but without leaving menu selection; after each character completion is tried again and the list changes to contain only the new matches; the completion widgets make the longest unambiguous string be inserted in the command line and undo and backward-delete-char go back to the previous set of matches
>
> -- [`zhmodules(1)` 22.7.3 Menu selection](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection)

---

It could be fine to see also [`edit-command-line`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-edit_002dcommand_002dline) for dealing with quite big command line buffers.

---

Now on my debian system, I can get the below effect:

```
# apt-get install perl-*<Tab><C-x><C-a><C-w>
;# ⇓
# apt-get install perl-base perl-byacc perl-cross-debian perl-debug perl-depends perl-doc perl-doc-html perl-modules perl-stacktrace perl-tk
```

Comment: On my zsh config I have zsh-syntax-highlighting loaded and it appears to conflict with all-matches if it is loaded _after_ the all-matches completer is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem, and it gets the job done, but it's not the kind of solution that I want.

I selected the completion text on my screen (I'm using mintty) and copied it into my editor. I then reformatted it like so:

```
perl perl-IPC-Run3 \
perl-ack perl-libwww \
perl-Archive-Zip perl-Locale-Gettext \
perl-Authen-SASL perl-LWP-MediaTypes \
perl-Benchmark-Timer perl-LWP-Protocol-https \
perl-Capture-Tiny perl-MailTools \
perl-common-sense perl-MIME-tools \
perl-Compress-Bzip2 perl-Mozilla-CA \
perl-Convert-BinHex perl-Net-DNS \
perl-Crypt-SSLeay perl-Net-HTTP \
perl-DBI perl-Net-IP \
perl-Digest-HMAC perl-Net-SMTP-SSL \
perl-Encode-Locale perl-Net-SSLeay \
perl-Error perl-Path-Class \
perl-Exporter-Lite perl-Probe-Perl \
perl-ExtUtils-Depends perl-Regexp-Common \
perl-ExtUtils-PkgConfig perl-Socket6 \
perl-File-Copy-Recursive perl-Sys-CPU \
perl-File-Listing perl-TermReadKey \
perl-File-Next perl-Test-Pod \
perl-File-Which perl-Test-Script \
perl-Getopt-Tabular perl-TimeDate \
perl-HTML-Parser perl-Try-Tiny \
perl-HTML-Tagset perl-URI \
perl-HTTP-Cookies perl-WWW-RobotRules \
perl-HTTP-Daemon perl-XML-LibXML \
perl-HTTP-Date perl-XML-NamespaceSupport \
perl-HTTP-Message perl-XML-Parser \
perl-HTTP-Negotiate perl-XML-SAX \
perl-IO-HTML perl-XML-SAX-Base \
perl-IO-Socket-INET6 perl-XML-Simple \
perl-IO-Socket-SSL perl-YAML \
perl-IO-stringy perl-YAML-Syck
```

And pasted it back into my terminal after `pacman -S`.

I've said that this isn't the kind of solution that I want, and so I should mention the sort of solution I'm looking for.

I'm looking for something like `pacman -S perl-*` which looks like it might glob up all of the completions or something (It doesn't).